# addSubview is not displayed UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I described `[self.view addSubView:myView];`,
but, myView is not displaying `self.view`.

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    UIView *myView;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *myView;
```

ViewController.m

```
@synthesize myView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    myView.frame = CGRectMake(-10, 70, 320, 480);
    [self.view addSubview:myView];
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:myView];
}
```

Do you have any solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to allocate your view first:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // If you use custom view change UIView to the custom class name
    myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-10, 70, 320, 480)];

    [self.view addSubview:myView];
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:myView];
}
```